# Expressjs mongoose user roles and role permissions using pivot

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a user schema as follows

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    otp: {
        type: String,
    },
    phone_number: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String,
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date,
    }
    
}, { timestamps: true });
```

role schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const roleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}, { timestamps: true })


export default mongoose.model('Role', roleSchema);
```

and user role schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userRoleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User",
        unique: true,
    },
    roleId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "Role",
        unique: true,
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

export default mongoose.model('UserRole', userRoleSchema);
```

I want to be able to get the user object with their corresponding role. How do I do that with mongoose? Is there a simple way of doing this instead of using pivots? Because in my design I have more objects connected using pivots.

User->userRole->Role
Also;

User->userPermission->Permission

I understand that I could use populate method for the relations but only when I have my roles and permission fields in the user schema with the reference to the role and permissions schemas

In simple terms I need a better way to link this schema objects instead of getting the userRole then finding the rolename in the RoleSchema as below. I need to be able to get a clean user object with the role name as well as the user with permissions

```
let user =  User.getRole(1); // find user
let userRole = UserRole.where('userId',1); // determine the user role
let role = Role.findOne(userRole.roleId); // get the specific role
user.role = role.name; // add role name to user object
```

Same goes for the rolePermission pivot for the roles permissions and direct userPermission pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb [lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join collections.

```
  const userWithRoles = await User.aggregate([
    {
      "$match": {
        "_id": 1  // change accordingly
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "userRoles",  // must be the Physical collection name
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "userId",
        "as": "roles"
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "roles",  // must be the Physical collection name
        "localField": "roles.roleId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "roles"
      }
    }
  ])
})
```

Sample [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GI-OE-ygbJx)